# Validate new record against existing records

Tags: validation

So I have a custom object called properties
Properties has a master detail link to a person account, and there is a field called property type.

I only want to be able to assign one property type per person - so a person can only have 1 residential property.

I am currently writing a trigger to do this, but I think it could be done with validation rules - which would be better as then I would not need to write unit tests etc.

Comment: You've made a number of statements but it's unclear to me what you're asking. A validation rule can determine whether or not a value was entered for Properties. Workflow would be required to enter a value if it wasn't. Is that your question?

Answer (score 3):

Create a 1 roll-up summary field on Account per type of Property, where you summarize the number of Property records per type. Then write a validation rule on Account that states that your roll-up summary field value cannot be higher than 1.